# Regular expression not matching the expected data

Tags: text-processing, awk, regular-expression

I'm attempting to extract the data based on the filter criteria by the following `awk` command, but it's not functioning. Could you possibly fix this?

```
awk -v RS='' -v ORS='\n\n' '/func: peak*down*HIL/' filename
```

Input:

```
func: peak_rec_head_HIL
sub: xyz
value: adc
log:path
close:date

func: peak_some_down_head_HIL
sub: xyz
value: adc
log:path
close:date

func: peak_another_one_down_head_HIL
sub: xyz
value: adc
log:path
close:date

func: peak_rec_head_HIL
sub: xyz
value: adc
log:path
close:date

func: peak_another_one_down_head_joy_HIL
sub: xyz
value: adc
log:path
close:date
```

Expected output:

```
func: peak_some_down_head_HIL
sub: xyz
value: adc
log:path
close:date

func: peak_another_one_down_head_HIL
sub: xyz
value: adc
log:path
close:date

func: peak_another_one_down_head_joy_HIL
sub: xyz
value: adc
log:path
close:date
```

Comment: probably because `peak*down*HIL` should be `peak.*down.*HIL` ?

Comment: You're confusing shell globbing syntax where, in that context, `*` means `0 or more occurrences of any characters` with regular expression syntax where `*` means `0 or more repetitions of the preceding character`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is the regular expression.  You would need to replace each `*` by `.*` to match any number of any character between the substrings.

```bash
awk -v RS='' -v ORS='\n\n' '/func: peak.*down.*HIL/' file
```

Each `*` modifies the behaviour of the previous part of the expression, allowing it to match zero or more times. The expression `peak*down` would match any of `peadown`, `peakdown`, `peakkdown`, `peakkkdown` etc.

Since the format of your file is the same as used by [GNU recutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/recutils/), I would personally use `recsel` instead of `awk` to query (or generally work with) your data:

```bash
recsel -e 'func ~ "peak.*down.*HIL"' file
```

It's often better (easier, more robust, easier to maintain) to use tools aware of the data format than generic text-processing tools.